# Group by day and conditional count issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQLServer 2008r2 - I have a table which has records inserted every hour.  The relevant columns for my query are currentScore (int) and obsDate (smallDateTime).  I wish to get five records grouped by day.  Today, the two days prior to today (starting at mid-night) and two days in the future.   SO if its Jun 20 I want June 18, 19, 20, 21 and 22.  I am successfully doing this like so:

```
select dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, obsDate)) as theDate,  
count(currentScore) as numOfScores 
from diseaseScores
where siteID=8315 and obsDate > dateAdd(day, -2, (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 
CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) + '00:00'))   
group by dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, obsDate))
order by dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, obsDate))
```

My record set looks like so:

```
      theDate           numOfScores
2017-06-18 00:00:00.000    23
2017-06-19 00:00:00.000    22
2017-06-20 00:00:00.000    24
2017-06-21 00:00:00.000    24
2017-06-22 00:00:00.000     9
```

I wish to add three more columns which will count the number of currentScore in a certain range.  Something like this

```
CASE 
WHEN currentScore < 8 THEN COUNT(where currentScore < 8) as Low
WHEN currentScore > 8 and < 17  THEN COUNT(where currentScore > 8 and < 17) as Med
WHEN currentScore > 17 THEN COUNT(where currentScore > 17 ) as High
```

Can I do this with a select case?    What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Here is the result I wish to achieve:

```
 theDAte   numOfScores  low   med   high
 2017-06-18   23        23    0     0
 2017-06-19   22        22    0     0
 2017-06-20   24        5     19    0
 2017-06-21   24        0     24    0
 2017-06-22   9         0     9     0
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `cast(. . as date)`.  Much clearer!  Then you can do what you want using conditional aggregation:

```
select cast(obsDate as date) as theDate,  
       count(currentScore) as numOfScores ,
       sum(case when currentScore < 8 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_low,
       sum(case when currentScore >= 8 and currentScore < 17 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_medium,
       sum(case when currentScore >= 17 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_high
from diseaseScores
where siteID = 8315 and
      obsDate >= cast(getdate() - 2 as date)  
group by cast(obsDate as date)
order by cast(obsDate as date);
```

Note:  Your original `where` clause has only half the date condition.  I didn't add the other half, but it should be pretty obvious how to get no more than two days in the future.

Comment: Great, thank you. It just perfect.  I had a feeling that I was using CASE wrong.  It seems so obvious now when I look at you query.  Using cast as date removes the time therefore achieves my objective in much less characters also, great.   Thanks again Gordon, your time is appreciated!